# In RIP the data part why we are limiting to to 512 bytes

Tags: routes, udp

> In RIP packet the data size allowed is limiting to 512 bytes, which
>   includes RIP routes and MD5 authentication. We can use upto 1460 bytes
>   for ethernet why we are limited to use upto 512 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

IPv4 only assures an MTU of 576 bytes.  That includes headers such as IP and UDP.  Additional headers may be added by PPPoE, MPLS, IPsec, or other protocols.  512 is simply a round binary number that leaves some room for such headers.